# Vectorize method for N period moving slope

Tags: matlab, regression, vectorization

Can someone please help me vectorize a moving slope calculation.  I trying to eliminate the for loop but I am not sure how to do so.

```
>> pv = [18 19 20 20.5 20.75 21 21.05 21.07 21.07]'; %% price vector 

>> slen = 3; %% slope length

function [slope] = slope(pv , slen)
svec = (1:1:slen)';
coef = [];
slope = zeros(size(pv));

for i = slen+1 : size(pv,1)
      X = [ones(slen,1) svec];
      y = pv( (i - (slen-1)) : i );
      a = X\y;
      slope(i,1) = a(2); 
end

>> slp = slope(pv,3)

slp =
        0
        0
        0
     0.75
    0.375
     0.25
     0.15
    0.035
     0.01
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes sorry, it is slen (slope length).  I had renamed the variable before posting it and missed it.  I will edit it.  tks

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: completely changing answer to make it scalable

```
function [slope] = calculate_slope(pv , slen)  %% Note: bad practice to give a function and variable the same name

svec = (1:1:slen)';
X = [ones(slen,1) svec];

%% the following two lines basically create the all the sliding windows of length slen (as a submatrix of a larger matrix)
c = repmat ( flipud(pv), 1, length(pv))
d = flipud(reshape(c(1:end-1), length(pv)-1, length(pv) + 1));

%% then run MATLAB solver with all windows simultaneously
least_sq_result = X\d( end - slen + 1:end, (slen+1):end);
slope = [zeros(slen-1, 1); least_sq_result(2,:)'];  %% padding with zeros is optional
```

EDIT: fixed swapped indices

Comment: Thanks gariepy.  You are correct that I wanted to start the indexing with the highest index in the group.   Should this method work for other values of slen?  I am trying slen = 5 and the two methods do not agree.

Comment: I realized there was a bug, I forgot to generalize the subscripts in the second `pv` expression.  You are correct, for higher values of `slen` you will not get an exact match.  You have an over-determined system, and MATLAB performs a least-squares regression to produce an "average" slope, while my method relies on the old `rise/run` formulation of slope.

Comment: Thanks for you help.

Comment: Much for me to learn with that example.  Thank you.  I did notice this change needed to be made in the final line                                               slope = [zeros(slen-1, 1); least_sq_result(:,2)']; should be                     slope = [zeros(slen-1, 1); least_sq_result(2,:)'];  just the row and column reveresed on the least_sq_result matrix

Comment: @TBoggs: you are correct about the index swap...I have edited the answer to fix that issue. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @TBoggs: if one of the answers works for you, you can indicate that by choosing "Accept" to accept the answer to a question.  This lets future readers know that a solution was valid.  If these answers do not work, feel free to ask a new question!

Answer (score 0):

Finding the slope in a sliding window using least-squares regression is equivalent to first-order Savitzy-Golay filtering (using a differentiating filter). The concept of SG filtering is to perform local polynomial fits in a sliding window, then use the local model to smooth the signal or compute its derivative. When the data points are spaced equally in time (as they are here), the computation can be run very efficiently by pre-computing a set of filter coefficients, then convolving them with the data. This should be much faster than constructing a giant matrix and doing regression on it.

This is a pretty standard technique, and there's definitely existing matlab code floating around. Search for something like 'Savitzky-Golay differentiation'. Note that SG filters can also perform smoothing (the matlab builtin SG filtering functions do this), but you want the version that does differentiation.

> [Savitzky and Golay (1964)](https://dx.doi.org/10.1021%2Fac60214a047). Smoothing and Differentiation of Data by Simplified Least Squares Procedures

Comment: Thanks I will look up this method.  The method outlined above breaks down for large data sets.  Thanks.  I will see If I can get something to work with SG filtering and post back.